# VB.NET Generic Variable of unknown type

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics

In one of the methods, I need variable of unspecified generic type `Public Class SWTTField(Of dataType)` that will be instantiated only when type of `dataType` is know. However, I can't create a variable `Dim f As SWTTField` because it gives me an error `To few type arguments to SWTTField(Of dataType)`. How do I delay specifying type of generic variable, but still have a variable ?

Comment: An option would be to use interface. Have Dim f As ISWTTField and then initialize it f = New SWTTField(Of Something)

Comment: @the_lotus Interface has same issue, I have to create generic interface that has property that returns generic type. When creating variable of interface type, I would need to specify type as well.

Comment: If you cannot update existed classes to use Interface or to be derived from one base class. Then use `Object` type and cast it to type which you get to know later

Comment: @Fabio. That is something I am doing right now, and trying to go away from it, since the field will be accesses very often and it will need to cast to appropriate type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do that, you need to also make the class that uses it be generic.  For instance, let's say you had a class that used a generic list, like this:

```
Public Class Registry
    Private _items As New List(Of Object)()

    Public Sub Register(item As Object)
         _items.Add(item)
    End Sub
End Class
```

But you didn't want it to be a `List(Of Object)`.  Instead, you wanted it to be a `List(Of ?)` where it would be a list of some specific type, but you wanted to specify the type later elsewhere.  In a case like that, you'd just need to make the outer class be generic too, like this:

```
Public Class Registry(Of T)
    Private _items As New List(Of T)()

    Public Sub Register(item As T)
         _items.Add(item)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then, when you use the `Registry` class, you'd be forced to specify the type of the items that it registers:

```
Dim x As New Registry(Of User)()
```

Comment: I see what you are saying, but I can't really go back and change 50 or so classes to be generic and I don't have access to certain classes anyways.

Comment: Without more details about your specific problem, it's difficult to provide any other ideas.